# dotnet pack: version format

Tags: nuget, .net-core, pack

I'm packing my nuget package using **dotnet pack** command and before update my projects to dotnet core 1.1.2 and vs2017 I was able to put version of package with 4 numbers according our internal conventions (YEAR.RELEASE.PATCH.BUILD - 2017.02.01.123456).

After updating build number is always ignored and I can put it only in version suffix and this is not acceptable because nuget packages with version suffix is interpreted as prerelease.

How can I generate nuget package with 4 numbers in version?

My command is:

```
dotnet pack "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o ..\Build\Packages /p:Version="$build_version-b$build_nr" --include-symbols
```

Answer (score 1):

Using 4-part version numbers is still possible with the new .NET Core tooling, though you might hit limits in the version number support of .NET and NuGet: The limit of each component is `65534` - so `123456` is simply too high.

using

```
dotnet pack /p:Version=2017.02.01.12345
```

produces an `mylib.2017.2.1.12345.nupkg` as expected.